# how to add p-values to correlation plot using GGally

Tags: r, ggally

Is there a way to add p value for the correlation plot using "ggcorr" from the package "GGally"?

I only managed to add the pearson r value but not the p-value.

```
install.packages("ggcorr")
library("ggcorr")
ggcorr(iris[1:4], method = c("everything", "pearson"), label=TRUE)
```

Thanks!